# Merging answers to old questions, how it relates to acceptance and Necromancer

Tags: discussion, reputation, duplicate-questions, merged-questions, necromancer-badge

So I experienced my first merge yesterday, after a question I had answered was closed due to duplicate. I thought closed questions will be deleted along with the answers, and all generated reps nullified etc, which would've been a nightmare scenario, but in fact the process is as fair as anybody can ask for, and I even got a {Necromancer} badge along the way =)

Since then I've looked more aggressively for duplicates of questions where I've had given answers for, and I've already found plenty. However, I'm still not quite sure what to do here.

Supposedly *some* duplication is okay, and what counts as *exact* duplicate is always subject to debate. If I vote to close these questions for being exact duplicate, though, and enough people in the community vote for it as well, what will happen to my answer, and all the other good answers for that question? Is it guaranteed that they will all be merged into the reference question, even if there are differences between them that would require some edits so that it'd make sense in the new context? Is it possible that they'll just silently get deleted eventually and everybody would lose all their reps?

What happens if both questions already have accepted answers? Will one answer have to be unaccepted, -15 to one of them as a consequence?

If all these merges give me {Necromancer} badges, is that "gaming the system"? If yes, is it an acceptable side effect of the duplicate-close-merge actions for the benefit of the community?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Necromancer badge awarded for answer merged into old question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53302/necromancer-badge-awarded-for-answer-merged-into-old-question)

Comment: I don't agree this is a dupe; this question discusses the consequences of merging more than that it asks about the Necromancer badge. *And* it is the older of the two; the other post could perhaps be considered a dupe of this one instead.